# Logic behind recursive functions that calls itself more than once in itself

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I understand recursive functions with only one nested function, such as this one:

```
def recurseInfinitely( n ):   
    try:
        recurseInfinitely(n+1)
    except RuntimeError:
        print("We got to level %s before hitting the recursion limit." % n)
```

This function calls itself until hits the barrier, which is 998 times.

But when a function calls itself for two times, things get really confusing for me.

This question is inspired from a video on youtube which explains recursion and solves a problem called **Tower of Hanoi** via using Python.

[Recursion 'Super Power' (in Python) - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lhxIOAfDss&t=620s)

I changed the functions to these:

```
def move(x, y, name):
    print("   {} Move from {} to {}".format(name, x,y))

def hanoi(n_of_disks,from_position,helper_position,target_position, name):
    if n_of_disks==0:
        print("#name: %s do nothing if there's no disk: %d" % (name, n_of_disks))
        pass
    else:
        # --> A
        print("Before A, name: %s disk: %d" % (name, n_of_disks))
        hanoi(n_of_disks-1,  # 3
            from_position,   # A
            target_position, # C
            helper_position, # B
            name='FIRST RECURSOR') 

        move(from_position,  # A
            target_position, # C
            name) 

        # --> B
        print("Before B, name: %s disk: %d" % (name, n_of_disks))
        hanoi(n_of_disks-1,  # 3
            helper_position, # B
            from_position,   # A
            target_position, # C
            name='SECOND RECURSOR')
```

And ran it...

```
hanoi(n_of_disks=4,
      from_position='A',
      helper_position='B',
      target_position='C',
      name="START THE SHOW")
```

The result is:

```
Before A, name: START THE SHOW disk left: 4
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 3
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to B
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to C
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from B to C
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to B
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 3
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from C to A
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from C to B
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from A to B
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   START THE SHOW Move from A to C
Before B, name: START THE SHOW disk left: 4
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 3
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from B to C
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from B to A
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from C to A
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from B to C
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 3
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to B
Before B, name: FIRST RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from A to C
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 2
Before A, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: FIRST RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
   SECOND RECURSOR Move from B to C
Before B, name: SECOND RECURSOR disk left: 1
#name: SECOND RECURSOR do nothing if there's no disk: 0
```

Some Questions:

1. Why it acts like its threaded?
2. Why it counts back from 4 to 1 at the very beginning, and later does that again?
3. Why the first move is not from A to C, instead, it is from A to B?
4. Is recursion really something useful in real life?
   From what I've read, it is:

   - (-)Resource expensive
   - (-)Slower
   - (+)Easier to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the purpose of this code, but I do understand recursion.

As you wrote it, the function `recurseInfinitely` is a **terminal recursive** function. Which means that the recursive call is the very last operation to be done in the function. Therefore the execution of such function is linear :

```
recurseInfinitely(0)
└─ recurseInfinitely(1)
   └─ recurseInfinitely(2)
      └─ ...
```

At the opposite, the function `hanoi` is not terminal recursive since it calls twice itself. The execution looks like a binary tree. For example with `n = 3` :

```
hanoi(3,A,B,C)           3
├─ hanoi(2,A,C,B)        2
│  ├─ hanoi(1,A,B,C)     1
│  │  ├─ hanoi(0,A,C,B)  0
│  │  └─ hanoi(0,C,A,B)  0
│  └─ hanoi(1,C,A,B)     1
│     ├─ hanoi(0,C,B,A)  0
│     └─ hanoi(0,A,C,B)  0
└─ hanoi(2,B,A,C)        2
   ├─ hanoi(1,B,C,A)     1
   │  ├─ hanoi(0,B,A,C)  0
   │  └─ hanoi(0,C,B,A)  0
   └─ hanoi(1,A,B,C)     1
      ├─ hanoi(0,A,C,B)  0
      └─ hanoi(0,B,A,C)  0
```

which corresponds to you results.

In practice, such algorithm is to avoid since it grows **exponentially** with `n` (~`2^n`).

Concerning the usefulness of recursion, it is not true that recursion is more resource expensive or slower. However, what is true is that recursion isn't suited for all languages. In fact, some languages are entirely based on recursion (for example `Lisp`, `Scheme` and `SQL`). It is called **functional programming** and is, indeed, very elegant.

For example, in `Scheme` the factorial function could be written

```lisp
(define (fact n)
    (if (zero? n)
        1
        (* n (fact (- n 1)))
    )
)
```

One should note that this function is **not** terminal recursive since it does a multiplication after the recursive call.

A terminal version (using an accumulator) of it would be

```lisp
(define (fact n)
    (fact-acc n 1)
)

(define (fact-acc n acc)
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (fact-acc (- n 1) (* n acc))
    )
)
```

Comment: `hanoi` is just tree traversal and all tree traversals need recursion to be done. A good example was the first Fortran compiler which couldn't be implemented in Fortran since it did not support recursion. Source code parsing is of a very recursive nature.

Comment: @Sylwester Indeed, code parsing is a good example ! However, it is possible to implement tree traversals iteratively using queues/stacks.

Comment: The second you introduce a stack in that manner you are doing a recursive process and IMO not much different from writing the function recursive to begin with. Remember CPUs don't have `for` or `while` loops or functions with arguments. The features are all emulated by the language so I have no idea why someone would suggest a recursive function and a while loop with a stack is much different.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer all of your questions but I can answer:

> Why the first move is not from A to C, instead, it is from A to B?

Lets take it as a given that if n=2, the first move is to move A to B in these steps:

```
FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to B
START THE SHOW Move from A to C
SECOND RECURSOR Move from B to C
```

or we could have moved the tower to B with these steps

```
FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to C
START THE SHOW Move from A to B
SECOND RECURSOR Move from C to B
```

With this we've demonstrated that we can move the top two blocks to any position. Lets think of the case with n=3. We can move the top two blocks to either of B or C. However, to keep C free for the third block we need to move the top two blocks to B. This is shown below:

```
FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to C
FIRST RECURSOR Move from A to B
SECOND RECURSOR Move from C to B

START THE SHOW Move from A to C
FIRST RECURSOR Move from B to A
SECOND RECURSOR Move from B to C
SECOND RECURSOR Move from A to C
```

Once again we could move the top three blocks to either B or C since we could move the top two blocks to either B or C. This logic applies recursively meaning that the solution for the towers of hanoi for every odd number of disks begins with A to C and the even numbers of disks have a solution beginning with A to B.